# Another version of default parameters and also default function type? What is this alien javascript syntax

Tags: javascript

I don't understand this syntax, in a javascript library called Draft.js
I assume it's some sort of type casting but there's no context to it..
https://draftjs.org/docs/advanced-topics-key-bindings

```
function myKeyBindingFn(e: SyntheticKeyboardEvent): string {
  if (e.keyCode === 83 /* `S` key */ && hasCommandModifier(e)) {
    return 'myeditor-save';
  }
  return getDefaultKeyBinding(e);
}
```

Comment: That's not type *casting*, just type *checking*, to help during the build process

Comment: It may be written in `typescript`

Comment: Check facebook `flow` that is what you are looking for.

Comment: I see. But why would they go from standard javascript to typescript all of a sudden with no warning. I've never used typescript before. Thanks for the tip though guys.

Comment: It may not be required, and the types are there to make it clearer to the reader of the documentation what the inputs and outputs are, despite the fact that it can be written in vanilla JS (wild guess)

Comment: Many translate-to-JavaScript languages accept plain old JavaScript syntax too. And when I say "many" I mean I think at least one.

Comment: take a look of this article for details : https://itnext.io/why-use-typescript-good-and-bad-reasons-ccd807b292fb
and  : https://medium.com/tech-tajawal/typescript-why-should-one-use-it-a539faa92010

BTW it is an ease for the guys coming from strongly typed languages like C# or java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is flow syntax 
Functions have two places where types are applied: Parameters (input) and the return value (output).

```
// @flow
function concat(a: string, b: string): string {
  return a + b;
}
```

ref: https://flow.org/en/docs/types/functions/